# Converting Set of a Map to a Map

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help in converting an argument type from Set to a Map. I using batch update in my flutter code and '.toJson()' method to get the 'data'.

The warning I get is :

```
The argument type 'Set<Map<String,dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String,dynamic>'.
```

..for the 'data' part in batchUpdate command.

Is there any way to convert the set to a Map so batch.Update can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

We may first convert your `data` from .toJson() method like this code below :

```dart
// 1. As explained, toJson() results `data` typed as Set<Map<String, dynamic>>
Set<Map<String, dynamic> data = payload.toJson() 

// 2. Convert `data` type to Map<String, dynamic>
Map<String, dynamic> newData = data.single

// 3. then proceed `data` to next method
batchUpdate(data);
```